# Как поменять цвет кнопки в андроид, и вернуть обратно дефолтный цвет если нажата другая кнопка?

Tags: java, android

Как мне поменять цвет нажатой кнопки и вернуть его если нажата другая?

В этом коде я устанавливаю состояние кнопок, которое дальше использую. Но имеено в этом коде мне надо понять, как поменять цвет кнопки в зависимости от того, какую нажал юзер.

Нажата кнопка 1 - изменила свой серый цвет на зеленый. Потом юзер нажал кнопку 2 - кнопка 2 стала зеленой, а кнопка 1 стала снова серой.

Пробовал селекторамие но не получилось, возможно не правильно что-либо делал, при запуске приложения у меня открывался код xml-файла, где были селекторы прописаны, а приложение не запускалось.

Кнопки у меня прописаны так `androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton`

```
public void onClickVibro(View view) {
        int id = view.getId();
        if (id == R.id.buttonVib1) {
            state = 1;
        } else if (id == R.id.buttonVib2) {
            state = 2;
        } else if (id == R.id.buttonVib3) {
            state = 3;
        } else if (id == R.id.buttonVib4) {
            state = 4;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Есть такой виджет RadioButton, которые объединяются в RadioGroup. У него точно такое поведение, как тебе надо прямо "из коробки", в общем то он специально для этого задумывался. Так вот, стилизовать виджеты RadioButton можно под что угодно, в том числе и под обычную кнопку

Answer (score 0):

Для изменения цвета элементов управления используйте    `Button.setBackgroundColor(myColor);`
, где myColor-число в типе int, хранящий значения ARGB, для его получения используйте `myColor = Color.argb(Alpha, Red, Green, Blue);`
Пример:

```
View.OnClickListener OCL1= v-> { 
Button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb( 100, 100, 100));  
Button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb( 0, 200, 0)); 
};
View.OnClickListener OCL2= v-> { 
Button2.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb( 100, 100, 100));  
Button1.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb( 0, 200, 0)); 
};
Button1.setOnClickListener(OCL1);
Button2.setOnClickListener(OCL2);
```

Comment: Друг, ты не понял вопрос. Мне надо ставить разный цвет на разные кнопки  в зависимости от того какая кнопка нажата

Comment: Была нажата, или уже нажата?

Comment: Если вам нужно принимать уже нажатые кнопки, нужно использовать setOnClickListener()

Comment: У меня 4 кнопки, изначально у них у всех одинаковый цвет,надо менять цвет у крайней нажатой. Я же вроде норм написал в вопросе. Все кнопки сервые изначально при входе в прилку. Нажал кнопку 1 - она стала зеленой а все остальные также серыми, нажал кнопку 2 - она стала зеленой а кнопка 1 стала серой. Тобишь зеленым цветом должна быть выделена только одна кнопка, та которая была нажата крайней

Comment: В редакции я добавил для изменении цветов кнопок при нажатии, там у меня случай с 2 кнопками, но можно сделать для четырех